# Получить дробь (c/d) из дроби (a/b) прибавляя 1 к числителю и знаменателю и сокращая дробь

Tags: c++, олимпиада

написал такой код(Задача на картинке), не проходят большая половина тестов.

Так как условие на украинском переведу на русский:
Дроби, как известно, давняя слабость Степана. Вот и сейчас он берет правильную несокращаемую дробь(a/b) и делает с ней следующие операции : к числителю и знаменателю дроби добавляет 1, потом дробь сокращает до несокращаемой.
   Степана заинтересовал вопрос, можно ли такими операциями из дроби (a/b) получить дробь (c/d)? Помогите Степану.

Формат входных данных
Входной файл вмещает 4 числа:
a b c d

0 < a < b <= 10(5)

0 < c < d <=10(5)

числа a и b взаимно-простые, c и d - взаимно-простые, a/b != c/d. Числа записаны в столбик

Формат выходных данных

Выведете одно натуральное число - сколько описанных операций нужно сделать, чтобы из дроби a/b получить дробь c/d. Если этого сделать нельзя вывести 0.

Тот код что написал я работает с приведенным на картинке примером, и еще пару тестов проходит. Из 22 - 8 пройдены.

Помогите сделать работающий код, или обьясните в чем ошибка, пожалуйста.

[image: Задача]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main() {

ifstream inp;
ofstream otp;
inp.open("input.txt");
otp.open("output.txt");

int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, d = 0, ans = 0, a1 = 0, b1 = 0;

inp >> a >> b >> c >> d;
a1 = a;
b1 = b;

for (int i = 0; i > -1; i++) {
    if (i == 0) {
        if (a == c && b == d) {
            otp << i;
            break;
        }
        else {
            a += 1;
            b += 1;
            if (a == c && b == d) {
                otp << i + 1;
                break;
            }
            else if (a % 2 == 0 && b % 2 == 0) {
                a /= 2;
                b /= 2;
                if (a == c && b == d) {
                    otp << i + 1;
                    break;
                }
                else {

                }
            }
            else {

            }
        }
    }
    else {
        if (a == c && b == d) {
            otp << i;
            break;
        }
        else if (a == a1 && b == b1) {
            otp << 0;
            break;
        }
        else {
            a += 1;
            b += 1;
            if (a % 2 == 0 && b % 2 == 0) {
                a /= 2;
                b /= 2;
                if (a == c && b == d) {

                }
                else {
                    otp << i;
                    break;
                }
            }
            else {

            }
        }   
    } if (i > 1000000) {
        otp << 0;
        break;
    }
}

return 1;
```

}

Comment: сокращать дроби нужно правильно. А у Вас просто проверяется, что можно поделить на два. Подозреваю, что дробь вида 4/8 сократите лишь до 2/4 (а нужно до 1/2). Также в коде есть дубликат кода и пустые условия.

Comment: @KoVadim а как мне сделать чтобы дробь сокращалась до несокращаемой?(Реализовать в коде)

Comment: @KoVadim Задал глупый вопрос... нужно найти НОД и поделить дробь на него, я это реализовал, прошел 11 тестов из 22. Есть ещё варианты почему код не работает? Теперь уже этот : https://ideone.com/SXpWzk

Comment: новый код не будет сокращать дробь вида 6/15, так как 15 - непарное

Comment: @KoVadim разве можно сокращать дробь не через НОД?

Comment: @KoVadim Я сам написал код, работает. Прошел все тесты.

Comment: @KoVadim https://ideone.com/TmhH79

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дописал свой код, добавил сокращение дроби через НОД, все тесты пройдены.

Просмотреть код : https://ideone.com/TmhH79
Или ниже.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int Nod(int a, int b)
{
while (b ^= a ^= b ^= a %= b);
return a;
}
int main() {

ifstream inp;
ofstream otp;
inp.open("input.txt");
otp.open("output.txt");

long long int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, d = 0, ans = 0, a1 = 0, b1 = 0, x = 0;

inp >> a >> b >> c >> d;
a1 = a;
b1 = b;

for (int i = 0; i > -1; i++) {
    if (i == 0) {
        if (a == c && b == d) {
            otp << i;
            break;
        }
        else {
            a += 1;
            b += 1;
            if (a == c && b == d) {
                otp << i;
                break;
            }
            else  {
                if (a % Nod(a, b) == 0 && b % Nod(a, b) == 0) {
                    x = Nod(a, b);
                    a /= x;
                    b /= x;
                    if (a == c && b == d) {
                        otp << i + 1;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        if (a == c && b == d) {
            otp << i;
            break;
        }
        else if (a == a1 && b == b1) {
            otp << 0;
            break;
        }
        else {
            a += 1;
            b += 1;
            if (a % Nod(a, b) == 0 && b % Nod(a, b) == 0) {
                x = Nod(a, b);
                a /= x;
                b /= x;
                if (a == c && b == d) {
                    otp << i + 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }


    if (i > 1000000) {
        otp << 0;
        break;
    }
}

return 1;
}
```